# INTERLIS - Catalogue items duplicated on --import

Tags: interlis

### Problem

With every import (ili2db `--import` option) of xtf data having a data model with Catalogue data (enumeration values) the Catalogue items are also imported and thus the enumeration values ​​are duplicated. The option `--createBasketCol` is used because update (ili2db `--update` option) etc. is planned later. Omitting this option is therefore not a solution.

### Test

Test data: The ASTRA model [*RoadTrafficAccidentLocation*](https://models.geo.admin.ch/ASTRA/) is used to explain the problem.

Generate the *master* database:

- Create the *master* database: `ili2gpkg --schemaimport --dbfile ./GIS/Data/RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_master.gpkg --createBasketCol --createEnumTabs RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_V2.ili`.
- Import the Catalogue data: `ili2gpkg --import --importBid --dbfile ./GIS/Data/RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_master.gpkg RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_Catalogs_V2.xml`.

Data collection (survey1):

- Create the *survey1* database *RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_survey1.gpkg* with QGIS Model Baker (option *Source = Interlis (use GeoPackage)*).
- Import of the Catalogue data, equal as with the *master* database: `ili2gpkg --import --importBid --dbfile ./GIS/Data/RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_survey1.gpkg RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_Catalogs_V2.xml`.
- The recorded data must be assigned to a basket (field *T_Basket*). Therefore generate data records within the tables *T_ILI2DB_DATASET* and *T_ILI2DB_BASEKT*:

  - `insert into T_ILI2DB_DATASET (datasetName) values ('RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_V2.RoadTrafficAccident');`.
  - `insert into [T_ILI2DB_BASKET] ([dataset], [topic], [T_Ili_Tid], [attachmentKey], [domains]) values ((select T_Id from T_ILI2DB_DATASET where datasetName = 'RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_V2.RoadTrafficAccident'), 'RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_V2.RoadTrafficAccident', 'fb34beac-1d2b-4466-9a25-f83809d0fe35', 'RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_V2.RoadTrafficAccident', NULL);`.
- Record fictitious data with QGIS.

Import data from survey1 to *master*:

- Export from *RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_survey1.gpkg*: `ili2gpkg --export --baskets fb34beac-1d2b-4466-9a25-f83809d0fe35;b01 --dbfile ./GIS/Data/RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_survey1.gpkg RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_survey1.xtf` *)
- Import to *master*: `ili2gpkg --import --importBid --baskets fb34beac-1d2b-4466-9a25-f83809d0fe35;b01 --dbfile ./GIS/Data/RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_master.gpkg RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_survey1.xtf`.

*) Without including the basket *b01* of the Catalogue data, error messages occur: *Error: unknown referenced object RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_V2.RoadTrafficAccidentCatalogs.AccidentSeverityCategory TID 25 referenced from RoadTrafficAccidentLocation_V2.RoadTrafficAccident.Road-traffic-ec483-4ccident*.

Problem duplicated catalog data in *master*:

[image: Catalog items duplicated on each --import]

**Question**: How can it be avoided that the Catalogue data is (respectively must be) included with each import into the *master* database and thus is duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the model RoadTrafficAccidentCatalogs, the catalog items do not have a stable ID. You have to overrule the model.

One way to do this: use --createTidCol at schemaimport time and --importTid at data import time, and --exportTid at data export time.

Another way is: use the ili2db.oid metaattribute in a metaattibute file and option --iliMetaAttrs at schema import time.